# mySQL SELECT from multiple tables gives wrong information

Tags: mysql

Whenever I try to select something I receive a wrong outcome. I am trying to

```
SELECT voornaam, achternaam, transportmiddel
FROM Werknemer, Transportmiddel;
```

Which SELECTS the firstname, lastname and transporttype FROM the table Werknemer & Transportmiddel.
However.. When I perform this select, myQSL responds with

```
Meindert Stijfhals Fiets
Maarten Heylen Fiets
Meindert Stijfhals Auto
Maarten Heylen Auto
```

In my inserts however, I defined this:

```
INSERT INTO Winkel values
(0001 , 'xxx', 'xxx');
INSERT INTO Winkel values
(0002 , 'xxx', 'xxx');
INSERT INTO Werknemer values
(0100, 'Meindert', 'Stijfhals', 'xxx', 'xxx', 0001, 007);
INSERT INTO Werknemer values
(0101, 'Maarten', 'Heylen', 'xxx', 'xxx', 0002, 003);

INSERT INTO Transportmiddel values
(1, 'fiets', 20);
INSERT INTO Transportmiddel values
(2, 'auto', 0);
INSERT INTO Werknemer_Transport values
(0100, 1);
INSERT INTO Werknemer_Transport values
(0101, 2);
```

So I'm pretty sure that I just said that Meindert Stijfhals (0100) uses fiets, and Maarten Heylen (0101) uses auto.
These tables are used here:

```
CREATE TABLE Werknemer (
    personeelsnummer int(4) not NULL,
    voornaam varchar(10) not NULL,
    achternaam varchar(10) not NULL,
    adres varchar(30) not NULL,
    telefoon varchar(10) not NULL,
    winkelnummer int(4) not NULL,
    dokternummer int(3) not NULL,
    foreign key(winkelnummer) references Winkel(winkelnummer),
    foreign key(dokternummer) references Dokter(dokternummer),
    primary key(personeelsnummer)
);

CREATE TABLE Transportmiddel (
        transportnummer int (1) not NULL,
        transportmiddel varchar(15) not NULL,
        bonus_in_euro int(5) not NULL,
        primary key(transportnummer)
    );

CREATE TABLE Werknemer_Transport (
    personeelsnummer int(4) not NULL,
    transportnummer int(1) not NULL,
    primary key(personeelsnummer, transportnummer),
    foreign key(personeelsnummer) references Werknemer(personeelsnummer),
    foreign key(transportnummer) references Transportmiddel(transportnummer)
);
```

This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE Klant (
    klantnummer int(10) not NULL,
    voornaam varchar(10) not NULL,
    achternaam varchar(10) not NULL,
    adres varchar(30) not NULL,
    e_mail varchar(40) not NULL,
    primary key(klantnummer)
);

CREATE TABLE Winkel (
    winkelnummer int(4) not NULL,
    winkelnaam varchar(20) not NULL,
    winkeladres varchar(30) not NULL,
    primary key(winkelnummer)
);

CREATE TABLE Klant_Winkel (
    klantnummer int(10) not NULL,
    winkelnummer int(4) not NULL,
    primary key(klantnummer, winkelnummer),
    foreign key(klantnummer) references Klant(klantnummer),
    foreign key(winkelnummer) references Winkel(winkelnummer)
);

CREATE TABLE Leverancier (
    leveranciernummer varchar(3) not NULL,
    naam varchar(30) not NULL,
    adres varchar(30) not NULL,
    telefoon varchar(10) not NULL,
    winkelnummer int(4) not NULL,
    foreign key(winkelnummer) references Winkel(winkelnummer),
    primary key(leveranciernummer)
);

CREATE TABLE Artikel (
    artikelnummer int(5) not NULL,
    barcodenummer int(5) not NULL,
    artikelnaam varchar(20) not NULL,
    descriptie varchar(256),
    korting int(5),
    stock int(5) not NULL,
    type_voeding varchar(10) not NULL,
    primary key(artikelnummer)
);

CREATE TABLE Artikel_Winkel (
    winkelnummer int(4) not NULL,
    artikelnummer int(5) not NULL,
    primary key(winkelnummer, artikelnummer),
    foreign key(winkelnummer) references Winkel(winkelnummer),
    foreign key(artikelnummer) references Artikel(artikelnummer)
);

CREATE TABLE Dokter (
    dokternummer int(3) not NULL,
    naam varchar(20) not NULL,
    adres varchar(30) not NULL,
    telefoon varchar(15) not NULL,
    primary key(dokternummer)
);

CREATE TABLE Werknemer (
    personeelsnummer int(4) not NULL,
    voornaam varchar(10) not NULL,
    achternaam varchar(10) not NULL,
    adres varchar(30) not NULL,
    telefoon varchar(10) not NULL,
    winkelnummer int(4) not NULL,
    dokternummer int(3) not NULL,
    foreign key(winkelnummer) references Winkel(winkelnummer),
    foreign key(dokternummer) references Dokter(dokternummer),
    primary key(personeelsnummer)
);

CREATE TABLE Shift (
    shiftnummer int(4) not NULL,
    datum varchar(10) not NULL,
    start_tijd varchar(5) not NULL,
    eind_tijd varchar(5) not NULL,
    primary key(shiftnummer)
);

CREATE TABlE Werknemer_Shift (
    personeelsnummer int(4) not NULL,
    shiftnummer int(4) not NULL,
    primary key(personeelsnummer, shiftnummer),
    foreign key(personeelsnummer) references Werknemer(personeelsnummer),
    foreign key(shiftnummer) references Shift(shiftnummer)
);

CREATE TABLE Jobfunctie (
    jobnummer int(4) not NULL,
    jobfunctie varchar(15) not NULL,
    salaris_in_euro int(10) not NULL,
    primary key (jobnummer)
);

CREATE TABLE Werknemer_Jobfunctie (
    personeelsnummer int(4) not NULL,
    jobnummer int(4) not NULL,
    primary key(personeelsnummer, jobnummer),
    foreign key(personeelsnummer) references Werknemer(personeelsnummer),
    foreign key(jobnummer) references Jobfunctie(jobnummer)
);

CREATE TABLE Transportmiddel (
    transportnummer int (1) not NULL,
    transportmiddel varchar(15) not NULL,
    bonus_in_euro int(5) not NULL,
    primary key(transportnummer)
);

CREATE TABLE Werknemer_Transport (
    personeelsnummer int(4) not NULL,
    transportnummer int(1) not NULL,
    primary key(personeelsnummer, transportnummer),
    foreign key(personeelsnummer) references Werknemer(personeelsnummer),
    foreign key(transportnummer) references Transportmiddel(transportnummer)
);



   /* INSERTS */

/* INSERT dokter */
INSERT INTO Dokter values
(007, 'xxx', 'adres', 'xxx');
INSERT INTO Dokter values
(003, 'xxx', 'adres', 'xxx');

/* INSERT Winkel & Werknemer */
INSERT INTO Winkel values
(0001 , 'xxx', 'xxx');
INSERT INTO Winkel values
(0002 , 'xxx', 'xxx');
INSERT INTO Werknemer values
(0100, 'Meindert', 'Stijfhals', 'xxx', 'xxx', 0001, 007);
INSERT INTO Werknemer values
(0101, 'Maarten', 'Heylen', 'xxx', 'xxx', 0002, 003);

/* INSERT Werknemer & Transportmiddel */
INSERT INTO Transportmiddel values
(1, 'fiets', 20);
INSERT INTO Transportmiddel values
(2, 'auto', 0);
INSERT INTO Werknemer_Transport values
(0100, 1);
INSERT INTO Werknemer_Transport values
(0101, 2);

/* INSERT Werknemer & Jobfunctie */
INSERT INTO Jobfunctie values
(0001, 'gerant', 2000);
INSERT INTO Jobfunctie values
(0002, 'arbeider', 1500);
INSERT INTO Werknemer_Jobfunctie values
(0100, 0001);
INSERT INTO Werknemer_Jobfunctie values
(0101, 0002);

/* INSERT Klant */
INSERT INTO Klant values
(0000000001, 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');

/* INSERT Leverancier van een winkel */
INSERT INTO Leverancier values
(009, 'xxx', 'adres', 'telefoon', 0001);

/* INSERT Werknemer & Shift */
INSERT INTO Shift values
(3000, '1/01/2016', '7:00', '17:00');
INSERT INTO Werknemer_Shift values
(0101, 3000);

/* INSERT Artikel & Winkel*/
INSERT INTO Artikel values
(87392, 76351, 'Chips', 'lekkere chips', NULL, 100, 'snoep');
INSERT INTO Artikel_Winkel values
(0001, 87392);
INSERT INTO Artikel_Winkel values
(0002, 87392);

SELECT voornaam, achternaam, transportmiddel
FROM Werknemer, Transportmiddel;
```

I have this problem with different SELECT commands aswell. Can anyone help me please? I assume it is because I have a Table between the 2 tables to connect them. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Your query performs a `CROSS JOIN` and thus creates a Cartesian Product of the two tables.

Comment: I looked up the CROSS JOIN statement and when I use that it still gives the same outcome. 4 rows, 2 rows aren't true.

Comment: You are already doing a CROSS JOIN. So, specifying CROSS JOIN will not change anything.

Comment: I suggest you go to [`SQL Zoo`](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SQL_Tutorial) and learn a bit about sub-queries and joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell the query how to join the tables.

```
SELECT w.voornaam, w.achternaam, t.transportmiddel
FROM Werknemer w
JOIN Werknemer_Transport wt ON wt.personeelsnummer = w.personeelsnummer
JOIN Transportmiddel t ON t.transportnummer = wt.transportnummer;
```

Answer (score 2):

Further to [Terrence Curran's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34561687/5579365) answer which provided a query which will work for your specific situation, it appears that you need to gain more understanding of how to join tables together using SQL queries.

Since your data is normalized and you understand the concept of tables being related by a common field(s). I recommend you look at [w3schools JOIN section of the SQL tutorial.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) This provides you with examples of queries for different types of join. Starting from the initial page link there are 6 pages with good short examples and easy to understand explanations.

The first page is the type of join you are looking for, and the same as Terrence's answer. `JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` are interchangeable.